# Isomorphic Redux app not registering Redux-Thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-framework, redux-thunk

I seem to have a weird bug. I'm currently using Redux isomorphically and am also including `redux-thunk` as the middleware for async actions. Here's what my store config looks like:

```
// Transforms state date from Immutable to JS
const transformToJs = (state) => {
  const transformedState = {};

  for (const key in state) {
    if (state.hasOwnProperty(key)) transformedState[key] = state[key].toJS();
  }
  return transformedState;
};


// Here we create the final store,
// If we're in production, we want to leave out development middleware/tools
let finalCreateStore;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  finalCreateStore = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);
} else {
  finalCreateStore = applyMiddleware(
    createLogger({transformer: transformToJs}),
    thunkMiddleware
  )(createStore);
}

// Exports the function that creates a store
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = finalCreateStore(reducers, initialState);

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('.././reducers/index', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('.././reducers/index');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

The weird part about this is that I don't think there's anything wrong with this file because my `createLogger` is applied just fine. It logs out all my actions and state, but the minute I return a function instead of an object in an action creator, the execution is lost. I've tried throwing in `debugger` statements, which never hit and reordering the middleware also doesn't seem to help.

```
createUser(data) {
    // This `debugger` will hit
    debugger;
    return (dispatch) => {
     // This `debugger` will NOT hit, and any code within the function will not execute
      debugger;
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(
          AppActionsCreator.createFlashMessage('yellow', 'Works!')
        );
      }, 1000);
    };
  },
```

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

DOH! I wasn't dispatching the action. I was only calling the action creator. Gonna have to get used to that with Redux!

How I *thought* I was invoking an action:
`AppActionCreators.createFlashMessage('some message');`

How to actually invoke an action in Redux:
`this.context.dispatch(AppActionCreators.createFlashMessage('some message'));`

Where `dispatch` is a method provided by the Redux store, and can be passed down to every child component of the app through React's `childContextTypes`

Comment: Maybe illustrate your answer with code. What your solution is and maybe even explain what went wrong so others may avoid the mistake.